# WPF MVVM - How to arrange ViewModels

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am working on a WPF application based on the MVVM pattern.

For a particular entity I have a Model containing the entity properties, a ViewModel which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and has some additional logic as well as exposing the properties of the Model and two Views, one for creating and one for editing the entity.

I create a single ViewModel for the edit and create Views and pass through an id for the entity when it is an edit so that the existing data can be retrieved.

What I can't work out is how to structure the ViewModels in this situation, namely:

1. Should I have an EntityViewModel as a property of an EditEntityViewModel where the EntityViewModel exposes the properties of the Model and the EditEntityViewModel handles the commands and other logic? If I do this then I don't think the EntityViewModel is notified of changes in the View.
2. Should I have two separate ViewModels who know nothing about each other?
3. Should I have a single ViewModel for the page which exposes the properties of the Model as well as handling the commands and other logic?
4. Something else?

I know that I should have one ViewModel per View but I'm not entirely sure how to define what a separate view is. You can probably tell that I'm a bit confused as to how exactly to implement the framework.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't over complicate it.  Try to keep your view-model to model relationship 1:1.  As a result, your view-model will expose methods to support all CRUD methods on the model.  Also, consider using one view, not two.  There's a lot of overlap between them, so I think it makes sense.  You'll have fewer classes to write and maintain.  I think #3 on your list, using the one view approach, is your best option.

Comment: Thanks for this. It makes sense but what if I then have another view which uses an observable collection of the same entity for displaying multiple items. Up until now I have created an observable collection(Of EntityViewModel). If I follow what you have said and have a single ViewModel for this model then I would have logic inside it which would relate to multiple views. Does that make sense?

Comment: I try to keep my view-models lean and don't put much logic into them.  Maybe your logic belongs in a shared data access class or something similar?  I think it's acceptable to have your observablecollection<T> repeated in disparate view-models.

Comment: Having thought about it some more and taken on board what you said in your original answer I think I have a better understanding now of how to apply this. Thanks for all your help Big Daddy.